# Float Left and Float Right

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm modifying a website and have ran into some issues with my nav bar and main content appearing directly above one another.

You can see it here: http://kennedys.williamoconnor.me/

Does anybody know what in my CSS I can change to have the content appear beside one another? I believe it is float left on the id #left and float right on the id #content

I have two ID's within my #wrapper and I can't seem to get them to appear correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the margins from `#contentwrap`

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

1) Remove margin-top, and reduce margin-left to 20px

```
#contentwrap {
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}
```

2) Remove all margins and make #contentwrap float: right (example https://i.stack.imgur.com/sb6xl.png )

```
#contentwrap {
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
}
```

The first option is better in many cases, especially if you wanna change width or margins betweens div's.

Comment: Thank you. I have reduced margin-left to 20px and changed #left top: 56px to margin-top: 36px